# How to start replacing characters at some point?

Tags: java, csv, replace

It was very hard to form the question and I am sure it is still not clear.

I have a CSV file e.g.: Firstname;Lastname;Adress;product1;product2;product3;product4;

I would like to start replacing ";" with "::". The problem is, I want to start replacing after third semicolon.

I know it can be done in while loop where I check every character, when semicolon occurs I will count +1 and if counter is 3, I will start replacing. But isn't there a way how to do it without a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use indexOf(char,fromIndex) method.
Your third semicolon position search can be inlined :

```
csvLine.indexOf(';', csvLine.indexOf(';', csvLine.indexOf(';') + 1) + 1)
```

We assume that our csvLine has a least 3 semi-colons...

```
    String csvLine = "Firstname;Lastname;Adress;product1;product2;product3;product4";

    //Index of "fromIndex" param is inclusive, that's why we need to add 1
    int pos = csvLine.indexOf(';', csvLine.indexOf(';', csvLine.indexOf(';') + 1) + 1);

    //Retrieve string from the char after the third semi-colon
    String truncatedLine = csvLine.substring(pos + 1);

    //Replace ";" by "::" on our substring
    truncatedLine = truncatedLine.replaceAll(";", "::");

    //Then concat the first part of csvLine with the second
    String result = csvLine.substring(0, pos + 1).concat(truncatedLine); 

    System.out.println(result);  //Print => Firstname;Lastname;Adress;product1::product2::product3::product4
```

Poor input control and performance but we don't have any loops :)

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood what you want, try this.
First search se position of the third semicolon:

```
String csvContent = "Firstname;Lastname;Adress;product1;product2;product3;product4;";
int i = 0;
int index= 0;
while(i < 4){
  index = csvContent.indexOf(';', (index + 1));
  i++;
}//index = position of the thrid semicolon
```

Second, cut your CSV content at the index position.

```
String tmp1 = csvContent.substring(0, index);
String tmp2 = csvContent.substring(index, csvContent.length());
```

Thrid, replace all ';' by '::':

```
tmp2 = tmp2.replaceAll(";", "::");
```

Finaly, rebuild your file content:

```
csvContent = tmp1 + tmp2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
int pos = 0;
while (i < 3) {
    pos = string.indexOf(';', pos+1);
    i++;
}
String newString = string.substring(0, pos) +";"+ (string.substring(pos + 1, string.length()).replace(";", "::"));
```

Answer (score 0):

how about a regex solution?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?;.*?;.*?;)(.*)");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(str);

if(match.matches()) {
    String firstThree = match.group(1);
    String rest = match.group(2);
    rest = rest.replace(";", "::");
    return firstThree + rest;
}
```